# How to solve TypeError: items.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I have created a Redux reducer to navigate. Initially the localhost opens fine but when i go to another page and try going back there is an error stating the above.

Error

```
TypeError: items.map is not a function
HomeScreen
E:/College/DA/IWP/Book Fair/frontend/src/Screens/HomePage.js:26
  23 | return loading?<div>Loading...</div>:
  24 | error ?<div>{error}</div>:    
  25 | (
> 26 |   <ul className="items">
     | ^  27 | {
  28 |   items.map(book=>
  29 |     <li key={book._id}>
```

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
// import axios from 'axios';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { listItems } from '../actions/ItemsActions';



function HomeScreen(props){

  const bookList = useSelector(state=>state.bookList);
  const {items, loading, error} = bookList;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listItems());

    return() =>{
      
    };
  }, [])
  
  // Error that cannot render hence add below lines before ul
    return loading?<div>Loading...</div>:
    error ?<div>{error}</div>:    
    (
      <ul className="items">
    {
      items.map(book=>
        <li key={book._id}>
          <div className = "book">
              <img className="bookimage"src = {book.image} alt = "book 1"></img>
              <div className="bookname"><Link to ={'/book/' + book._id}>{book.name}</Link></div>
              <div className="author">{book.author}</div>
              <div className="cost">Rs. {book.cost}</div>
      <div className="rating">Stars: {book.rating} ({book.numReview} Reviews)</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        )
    }
      
  </ul>
    )
    
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

This is the home page.

I am suspecting that while going back the HomePage reads a wrong function and items.map does not return map. I have tried changing the API links but it's not working.

Comment: Is the error seen in `HomeScreen()`?

Comment: Yes. When I first open it it works. But after navigating back to the Homescreen, I see the rror

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the `loading` prop is set to `False` on the subsequent time you returned to this page.

You may want to add a check before iterating over the `items` array.

```
{
  items.length > 0 && items.map(book=>
    <li key={book._id}>
      <div className = "book">
        <img className="bookimage"src = {book.image} alt = "book 1"></img>
        <div className="bookname"><Link to ={'/book/' + book._id}>{book.name}</Link></div>
        <div className="author">{book.author}</div>
        <div className="cost">Rs. {book.cost}</div>
        <div className="rating">Stars: {book.rating} ({book.numReview} Reviews)</div>
       </div>
    </li>
     )
  }
```

Comment: It is working. Can you explain how this condition helps?

Comment: The condition ensures that `items` array is not iterated until it has contents inside. Like I mentioned, I suspect that `loading` was set to `False` on the subsequent times. So you might want to also look at how `loading` is set in the store

Comment: @Volpone do accept the answer if it solved your issue. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
Array.isArray(items) && items.map(book=>
        <li key={book._id}>
          <div className = "book">
              <img className="bookimage"src = {book.image} alt = "book 1"></img>
              <div className="bookname"><Link to ={'/book/' + book._id}>{book.name}</Link></div>
              <div className="author">{book.author}</div>
              <div className="cost">Rs. {book.cost}</div>
      <div className="rating">Stars: {book.rating} ({book.numReview} Reviews)</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

When your API called for the first time it does not return data at once so before sending your response you might want to check if the response you are returning is an array.

```
app.get("/api/items", (req, res)=>{

    if(Array.isArray(data.items)){

       res.send(data.items);
    }
    
});
```

Or in your client-side check if the items is an array before iterating to avoid the error.